How do you update a polygon table with count of points within, after adding one or more new points?
I have two tables (NAP_Boundary (polygon) & Sites (points)) in a PostgreSQL database enabled with POSTGIS. The NAP_Boundary table has a field called 'hhp_count' which is the count of valid site points within the boundary. The Sites table has a field called "included_in" which is an integer representing  1=no and 2 = yes. I have written the trigger on the NAP_Boundary table which gets the count of valid (included_in = 2) site points when either a polygon is inserted or a geometry is updated. This works fine for me. My issue is getting the trigger on the Sites table to update the NAP_Boundary table accurately. I am able to generate numbers, but they seem to be aggregating based on number updates, rather than by row.
I need triggers on both the NAP_Boundary and the Sites so that there are continuous updates in case either feature layer is changed.I am using QGIS as my spatial interface.
NAP Boundary example:



uuid
hhp_count
geom




{uuid}
5
(some geometry coords)


{uuid}
4
(some geometry coords)



Sites example:



uuid
included_in
geom




{uuid}
2 (yes)
(some geometry coords)


{uuid}
1 (no)
(some geometry coords)



CREATE OR REPlACE FUNCTION nap_site()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    WITH ts AS (
    SELECT nap.uuid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM  site s, nap_boundary nap
    WHERE ST_WITHIN(s.geom, nap.geom) AND s.include_in_build_plan = 2
    GROUP BY nap.uuid
    )
    UPDATE nap_boundary nap
    SET hhp_count = ts.cnt
    FROM ts
    WHERE nap.uuid = ts.uuid;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
-- on insert or update of geom
CREATE TRIGGER upd_num_addrs_in_nap_bound_site
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF geom, included_in
ON site
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE nap_site();

-- on Delete, we don't care about geom
CREATE TRIGGER nap_bound_site_del
BEFORE DELETE
ON site
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE nap_site();

For example, if I insert 1 new valid site point inside of an existing polygon, the hhp_count is updated by a count of 1, but if I insert 5 new valid site points inside of an existing polygon, the hhp_count is also updated by a count of 1. This is true if I append a large dataset of points, rather than insert manually.
Another example, I have two non-overlapping polygons with no existing points. I insert 3 valid sites in the first poly and 2 valid sites in the second poly. The updated hhp_counts are both 1.
If I update the "included_in" values rather than inserting new points, there is either no update to the "hhp_count" or once again, the updates are aggregated.
Any ideas what is causing this?
I have tried changing the SELECT nap.uuid statement to nap.geom, but this did not change the calculations. I have also tried disabling the trigger on the NAP_Boundary layer to check for interference with no change in effect. I have tried appending point data, adding and deleting points, and updating the "included_in" field, but the counts continue to return as as aggregations of that one update & save.
If a polygon has 1 valid existing point and 2 valid points are added during one update/save session, the hhp_count should be 3, but the trigger function returns 2.

it is a before update trigger but you are not consuming the NEW object, instead you are using the site table directly in your update statement, so the current updated/inserted row is ignored.  --> change to an after update trigger, or consume new.geometry instead of the whole table (and maybe old.geometry too)

@JGH Thank you, changing to 'after update' trigger worked for me.

How can I change the code to update the count within old polygon if a point is moved? Currently only the new polygon is updated if a point is moved.
